# Using Linux and .NET

Tags: .net, linux, ubuntu

I want to use Ubuntu Linux, but I cant because I need to programming in .NET
What can you advise me to do?

Comment: apt-get install monodevelop libmono-microsoft-visualbasic8.0-cil

Answer (score 3):

[mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) is an opensource version of the runtime that runs on linux and mac

---

Also Look to your right you may see an add that answers your question.  If ever there was a contra indication for the success of online advertising this post may be it.

Comment: They do have an ISO for OpenSUSE: http://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/download-stable/openSUSE_11.2

or

http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html

Comment: MonoTools (the ad I think you're referring to) is a Windows only solution.

but lol - targeted advertising does have its value sometimes

Answer (score 2):

You could always use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/). You could use a virtual machine and install Windows and Visual Studio in that.

Answer (score 1):

[Mono and MonoDev](http://monodevelop.com/), a virtual machine such as [QEmu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page), or if you are feeling brave, you can try using [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/), but it has limited compatibility with certain versions of [.NET](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2586) and [VisualStudio](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=892).

Answer (score 1):

Mono 2.4 is a great cross-platform implementation of the CLR.

Coupled with Mono, you can use [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) to edit normal VS .sln files.  It's not as powerful as Visual Studio, but still quite capable.

Answer (score 0):

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) is an opon source implementation of .NET. It still has it's flaws, but is rapidly evolving. For development, [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) might be a good choice.

But (especially if you have a hardware virtualization-capable cpu) the best thing you can do is to fire up vmware or virtualbox, and hava a small windows install at hand.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you dual boot Windows and Linux. Mono is solid, but it is still not as fully featured, especially in the Silverlight world. Moonlight is cool, but always a few steps behind.

Answer (score -2):

This is interesting, i don't know of anyway. You can write .net applications for linux using mono i think. And you can always write code in any editor.

Check microsoft websites to see if they have atleast a command line compiler for linux (honestly i dont know of one).