# working with .net on linux

Tags: .net, ubuntu, mono

I have some applications developed in asp.net, WPF ,windows Form etc.How can i run that in Ubuntu? Using some commands I installed MONO on Ubuntu. But I dont know more..
Can any one help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Linux and .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381322/using-linux-and-net)

Comment: You could at least answer the question, which is clear enough, guys

Comment: You'll want to accept some questions there Nikhil K if you expect people to keep helping you.  If you don't know how to check out the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using 'Ubuntu' not UBUNDU by the way.

Here's a getting started guide for Windows Forms that shows an app running on Mono:

> http://www.mono-project.com/WinForms_Getting_Started_Guide

And an FAQ for ASP.NET on Mono:

> http://mono-project.com/FAQ:_ASP.NET

(Did you google at all?  These were the first results!)

Answer (score 1):

A google search came up with some pretty good hits:

> http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&q=migrating+existing+application+to+mono&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

Getting started with Mono:

> http://mono-project.com/Start

Migration assistant:

> http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA

WPF won't work:

> http://mono-project.com/Compatibility

An in general the Mono site is very useful:

> http://mono-project.com